# Flutter Calendar - Showing custom data on days not works well

Tags: flutter, dart

I´m using flutter with a calendar carousel (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_calendar_carousel)

For each day for which there is an entry in the database, I want to display an icon in the calendar. What is the best way to do this?

**That´s my current code:**

Please check the part with the `customDayBuilder`

```
class _CalendarScreenState extends State<CalendarScreen> {
  DateTime _currentDate;

  openNewEntryDialog(BuildContext context, date) {
    setState(() {
      _currentDate = date;
    });
    showBarModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context, scrollController) {
          return AddCalendarEntry(
            scrollController: scrollController,
            currentDate: _currentDate,
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final calendarEntriesData = Provider.of<CalendarEntries>(context);

    void initState() {
      _currentDate = widget._currentDate;
      super.initState();
    }

    dayPressed(date, events) {
      this.setState(() => _currentDate = date);
    }

    return Material(
        child: CupertinoPageScaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
              trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () => openNewEntryDialog(context, DateTime.now())),
              middle: Text("Juni 2020",
                  style: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.textTheme.headline1),
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: CalendarCarousel(
                      markedDateIconBorderColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      weekdayTextStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                      daysTextStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                      todayButtonColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      locale: "de",
                      selectedDayButtonColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                      selectedDateTime: _currentDate,
                      headerTextStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: 25),
                      onDayPressed: (DateTime date, List<Event> events) =>
                          dayPressed(date, events),
                      onDayLongPressed: (DateTime date) =>
                          openNewEntryDialog(context, date),
                      customDayBuilder: (bool isSelectable,
                          int index,
                          bool isSelectedDay,
                          bool isToday,
                          bool isPrevMonthDay,
                          TextStyle textStyle,
                          bool isNextMonthDay,
                          bool isThisMonthDay,
                          DateTime day) {
                        return FutureBuilder(
                            future: calendarEntriesData.getAll(),
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<List<CalendarEntry>> snapshot) {
                              if (!snapshot.hasData ||
                                  snapshot.connectionState ==
                                      ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                return Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                );
                              } else {
                                for (final entry in snapshot.data) {
                                  var temp =
                                      DateTime.parse(entry.dateTime).toUtc();
                                  var d1 = DateTime.utc(
                                      temp.year, temp.month, temp.day);
                                  var d2 = DateTime.utc(
                                      day.year, day.month, day.day);
                                  if (d2.compareTo(d1) == 0) {
                                    return Center(
                                        child: Icon(Icons.local_airport));
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                          child: FutureBuilder<List<CalendarEntry>>(
                              future: calendarEntriesData
                                  .getCurrentMonthEntries(_currentDate != null
                                      ? _currentDate
                                      : DateTime.now()),
                              builder: (BuildContext context,
                                  AsyncSnapshot<List<CalendarEntry>> snapshot) {
                                if (!snapshot.hasData ||
                                    snapshot.connectionState ==
                                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                  return Center(
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  return Container(
                                      height: 100,
                                      child: ListView.builder(
                                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                              int index) {
                                            return ListTile(
                                              title: Text(snapshot
                                                  .data[index].servicePartner
                                                  .toString()),
                                              subtitle: snapshot.data[index]
                                                          .dateTime ==
                                                      null
                                                  ? Text("Unbekannt")
                                                  : Text(DateFormat(
                                                          "dd.MM.yyyy")
                                                      .format(DateTime.parse(
                                                          snapshot.data[index]
                                                              .dateTime))),
                                              trailing: Text((snapshot
                                                              .data[index]
                                                              .minutes /
                                                          60)
                                                      .toString() +
                                                  " Stunden"),
                                            );
                                          }));
                                }
                              })))
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

How you can see, I´m using a FutureBuilder to check all database entries. And if a day matches, I show an Icon on this day. This works in general, but

1. I have some errors on the screen
2. The performance is very bad, because there is some flickering..for each click on another day the widget renders completely. I don´t want this.

[image]

How could I improve my code? How could I do this better?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Please use the button and button style for this to generate a clickable.
Also resolved your issue.

```
    Widget renderDay(
    bool isSelectable,
    int index,
    bool isSelectedDay,
    //bool isToday,
    bool isPrevMonthDay,
    TextStyle? textStyle,
    TextStyle defaultTextStyle,
    bool isNextMonthDay,
    bool isThisMonthDay,
    DateTime now,
  ) {
    final EventList<T>? markedDatesMap = widget.markedDatesMap;
    List<Event> markedEvents =
        widget.markedDatesMap!.getEvents(now) as List<Event>? ?? [];
    return Container(
      child: ElevatedButtonTheme(
        data: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<BorderSide>((states) =>
                BorderSide(
                    color: ColorConstants.WHITE)),
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
              (states) => markedEvents.length > 0 &&
                      !isPrevMonthDay &&
                      !isNextMonthDay
                  ? _getStatusColor(
                      markedEvents[0].dayStatus!.toLowerCase())
                  : isSelectedDay && widget.selectedDayButtonColor != null
                      ? widget.selectedDayButtonColor
                      : widget.dayButtonColor,
            ),
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<OutlinedBorder>((_) {
              return RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80));
            }),
            textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<TextStyle>(
                (states) =>
                    TextStyle(color: ColorConstants.BUTTON_BG_COLOR)),
            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
              EdgeInsets.all(widget.dayPadding),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed:
              widget.disableDayPressed ? null : () => _onDayPressed(now),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              getDayContainer(
                  isSelectable,
                  index,
                  isSelectedDay,
                  // isToday,
                  isPrevMonthDay,
                  textStyle,
                  defaultTextStyle,
                  isNextMonthDay,
                  isThisMonthDay,
                  now),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```